# MySQL Error - Subconsulta devuelve mas de una linea

Tags: mysql, sql

He intentado hacer esta consulta

```
SELECT materia 
FROM Cursos 
WHERE idProfesor = (
    SELECT idProfesor FROM Profesores 
    WHERE nombreDepartamento='LSI');
```

Pero me la tira para atras porque la subconsulta devuelve 2 idProfesor. ¿Cómo hago para poder obtener todos los cursos asociados a los profesores cuyo nombreDepartamento sea 'LSI'?

Comment: TENGO ESE MISMO ERROR AL HACER ESTE UPDATE `UPDATE DIARIO_SAT DSAT SET DSAT.CORREOELECTRÓNICO =(select Cabezas.CORREOELECTRÓNICO from cabezas INNER JOIN diario_sat dsa ON dsa.num_rad_sat = cabezas.num_rad_sat WHERE (((DSA.CORREOELECTRÓNICO) Is Null) AND ((DSA.TIPO_AFIL) IN ('B'))));`

Answer (score 2):

Cambias el `=` por `IN`.

```
SELECT materia 
FROM Cursos 
WHERE idProfesor IN (
    SELECT idProfesor FROM Profesores 
    WHERE nombreDepartamento='LSI');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he conseguido con un Join. Por si alguien se encuentra con una duda similar lo he solucionado con:

```
SELECT C.materia FROM Cursos C 
JOIN Profesores P ON P.idProfesor=C.idProfesor
WHERE P.nombreDepartamento='LSI';
```